# How to mget files starting with a number in batch FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a batch file that gets files via FTP.  I'm able to "mget *", but I only want files that start with any number of numbers, followed by an underscore and then C.

I have:
mget [0-9]*_C*

so, for example, I want to get the file:  01234_C.TXT, but I don't want S01234_C.TXT

what's the syntax for getting a file that starts with numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP doesn't support regular expressions.

You would have to log an ftp session and get a list of the files, process that list locally and then create another script to `get` every file that matchs your filespec.